# Update Manager bug: Encountered a section with no Package: header

Tags: update-manager

I tried to do an update to my system (12.04 LTA 64bit, on ACER aspire V5) got this:

> Could not initialize the package information
>
> An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.
>
> Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:
>
> ```
> E:Encountered a section with no Package: header,
> E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_main_binary-i386_Packages,
> E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
> ```

Now What?

Answer (score 73):

Please do:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

The first command will remove the damaged list and when you run the second command it will replace it with a new list.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

all should be fixed.