# sudo apt-get update failing - "could not open" list file due to "permission denied"

Tags: apt, package-management, permissions, updates, update-manager

For the last week or more, running `sudo apt-get update` culminates in error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  
Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/au.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/au.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Entering either of the 2 specified urls into a browser address bar results in a 'File not found' (404) error - but if I append `.gz` to both addresses, then the respective files can be downloaded.

However, having downloaded the 2 files, I then don't know how (or if) I can utilize them.

Seeking advice on how best to proceed.

Answer (score 57):

The contents of that directory are partially downloaded lists (perhaps APT was interrupted?) which can be safely removed.

Start a root shell, being aware that you now have permission to do all kinds of damage to your system, so be careful (we need to do this because `sudo rm` errors out)

```
sudo -i
```

Remove the contents of the directory (type carefully) and exit the root shell:

```
rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
exit
```

Then run an APT update to regenerate the package lists and check the problem is gone:

```
sudo apt update
```

Comment: @Zana On my system, removing the files in `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/` didn't solve the pb. I had to remove the `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/` directory. The `sudo apt update` recreates it anyway.

Comment: Neither of these fixed my problem - had to do one level higher as mentioned here https://askubuntu.com/a/454899/839600

Comment: @DaveGriffiths good to know - I wonder if things have changed... not sure how to investigate it

Comment: This should be built into `apt-get update`

Answer (score 9):

Solution nearest to [@Zanna answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/917613/214624) But include save old APT lists folder as backup first before delete partial file from APT lists folder.

First clean APT

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Make backup APT list folder

```
sudo cp -r /var/lib/apt/lists /var/lib/apt/lists.old
```

Remove partial folder from APT List folder

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/
```

Then clean and update APT

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Source from [Ubuntu form post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1910598&p=11625057#post11625057)