# Permission denied to access files in /var/apt/lists/partial when I run sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, package-management, permissions

I have errors when trying to update my packages list with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Can you help me fix this?

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu xenial InRelease     
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Ign:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:6 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
Get:7 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]  
Ign:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb stable InRelease             
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fontforge/fontforge/ubuntu xenial InRelease     
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:11 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                             
Hit:12 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                    
Hit:13 http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb stable Release        
Ign:14 http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian lsb3.2 InRelease
Get:15 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main Sources [3 428 B]
Get:16 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Sources [4 948 B]
Get:17 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages [4 860 B]
Get:18 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages [4 856 B]
Get:19 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3 328 B]
Get:20 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages [6 624 B]
Get:21 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages [6 604 B]
Get:22 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Translation-en [3 768 B]
Get:23 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4 676 B]
Ign:24 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:24 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:24 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/fr.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_universe_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 194.158.119.186 80]
Hit:27 http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian lsb3.2 Release 
Fetched 204 kB in 0s (213 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:92
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:92
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:92
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-fr_FR) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:92
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-fr) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:92
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_US.UTF-8 git) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:92
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:92
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:92
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:92
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-fr_FR) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-fr) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_US.UTF-8 git) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/dists/lsb3.2/Release.gpg: Signature by key E5220FB7014D0FBDA50DFC2BE5E86C008AA65D56 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/fr.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_universe_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 194.158.119.186 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:92
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:92
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:92
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-fr_FR) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:92
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-fr) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:92
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_US.UTF-8 git) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:92
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:92
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:92
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:92
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-fr_FR) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-fr) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_US.UTF-8 git) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
```

**EDIT** : Errors after removing duplicates in repo list:

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu xenial InRelease     
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:5 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
Ign:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb stable InRelease             
Get:6 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]  
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fontforge/fontforge/ubuntu xenial InRelease     
Hit:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb stable Release              
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease             
Hit:13 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                             
Ign:16 http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian lsb3.2 InRelease     
Get:17 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main Sources [3 428 B]
Get:18 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Sources [4 948 B]
Get:19 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages [4 860 B]
Get:20 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages [4 856 B]
Get:21 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3 328 B]
Get:22 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages [6 624 B]
Get:23 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages [6 604 B]
Get:24 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Translation-en [3 768 B]
Get:25 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4 676 B]
Ign:26 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Hit:27 http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian lsb3.2 Release       
Ign:26 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:26 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/fr.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_universe_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 194.158.119.186 80]
Fetched 102 kB in 0s (107 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/dists/lsb3.2/Release.gpg: Signature by key E5220FB7014D0FBDA50DFC2BE5E86C008AA65D56 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/fr.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_universe_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 194.158.119.186 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try Synaptic open tab -> repositories ->Software & Updates ->other software and then check if there are duplicates in repos

This answer will help remove the partially downloaded lists : [sudo apt-get update failing - "could not open" list file due to "permission denied"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917603/sudo-apt-get-update-failing-could-not-open-list-file-due-to-permission-deni)

Comment: Thanks Yurij, I removed some duplicates in the repo list, and I still have errors with `sudo apt update`. I added the new log to the question.

Comment: Possible the solution posted there [sudo apt-get update failing - “could not open” list file due to “permission denied”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917603/sudo-apt-get-update-failing-could-not-open-list-file-due-to-permission-deni) 
also i note some warnings **W:** about weak digest algo and some repos are skiped - **Ign:**

Comment: Thanks Yurij, this solution worked and it's way cleaner now. Do you know what can I do about the W: and the lgn: ?